# Spring MVC session resource is getting shared by logged users

Tags: spring-mvc, session, tomcat8

I have deployed a web application using **Apache tomcat 8, java 8 and centos server** in production.

When i tested the system by 5-6 users concurrently in office network everything seemed ok. But in client network, one users info is getting by another user(session attributes are shared/mixup). For example, if user A logs in, after a while his name is showing user B, who is logged in from different computer. If user presses Ctrl+R then his/her previous session restores for a while.

N.B. this scenario never happens other than that client network. They are using specific proxy. Other than proxy, this scenario does not happen.

I have a simple LoginController class without defining any scope. Some code snippets are below:

```
 1. Login GET method:
    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getLogin(@ModelAttribute LoginForm loginForm)
    {
        return "login";
    } 
 2. Login POST method:
    @RequestMapping("/login", RequestMethod.POST) 
    public String Login(@ModelAttribute LoginForm loginForm, HttpSession session) 
    {  
        User dbUser = this.userService.getUser(loginForm.getUserID()); 
        if (dbUser != null)
        {
           if(passwordCheckedSuccess(dbUser.getPassword(), loginForm.getPassword()))   
           {
              session.setAttribute("userName", dbUser.getUserName());
              session.setAttribute("userId", dbUser.getUserId()); // primary key of user class        
              return "dashboard";
          }
          else
          {
            return "login";
          }
        }
    }
 3. I have created a loginIntercptor class to filter secured pages:
  public class LoginInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter
  {
    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception
    {
        if (!request.getRequestURI().endsWith("/login"))
        {
            if (request.getSession().getAttribute("userId") == null)
            {
                response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/login");
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
  }
```

I am not using spring security. 
Please suggest a way to get rid of it. Thanks.

Comment: This is not a complete example. I assume you know what an MCVE is?

Comment: any update @sarwar026 vai?